# Blazor WebAssembly - How can I add a new *.razor page that don't need to recompile or rebuild the project

Tags: asp.net-core, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I am developing a survey project which collects data from the client with Blazor WebAssemly for the Client-side. Each survey form will have a different design and edit-checked rule. So I decide when I create a new survey form, the application will generate a new *.razor page automatically, for example, `ClientSurvey.razor` page. Everything works well until I navigate the web application to the `ClientSurvey.razor` I just have created. The system shows error:

> 404 Not found.

I have to rebuild the project again, and it can show the `ClientSurvey.razor` page on my website.
With ASP.NET MVC before I don't have to rebuild the project when I add a new aspx page. Does it still work with Blazor WebAssembly? If yes, how can I change the razor page, and it can update on my website automatically without rebuild or recompile?

And I also meet a problem that when I deploy the project in IIS, I don't see where the UI (.*razor) pages are stored, I know they are compiled to dll. How can I keep them in raw files in the same way with ASP.NET work? With ASP.NET, when I deploy it in IIS, there is always a folder to store `aspx` pages.

Updated: please see the figure to more clearly
[image]

Comment: Let's show your code or your question will be deleted.

Comment: This is a question asking about the process deployment and configuration, so I didn't post code.

Comment: So in the first part of the question, you're asking if without (re)building during an active localhost session, will the changes you make to the razor page get automatically updated to the live localhost session?

And in the second part you're asking how to deploy blazor app to IIS?

Comment: I'm afraid the second requirement is impossible to realize...